# Client for Google API PHP Client and nested requires?

Tags: wordpress, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to implement Google analytics api in a wordpress dashboard plugin.

Following the simplest implementation for using the Google API for PHP for the first time, its not working right away at practically the first step.

According to the tutorial README.md, my app, placed ajacent to the library folder, should load the library like so:

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Books.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
```

Now, the structure of the library within my app (plugin) is:

```
myapp.php
/Google
/Google/Client.php
/Google/otherfolders/otherfiles.php
```

and my app attempts to load the library per the require_once above. But of course the Client.php has many require_once calls itself such as:

```
require_once 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';
```

Which seem to ignore its position -- already within /Google.

So I'm getting errors:

```
PHP Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <wpengine host path removed>/wp-content/plugins/mmstats/Google/Client.php on line 18
```

and

```
PHP Fatal error: require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in <wpengine host path removed>/wp-content/plugins/mmstats/Google/Client.php on line 18
```

This PHP is listed as "Beta" but surely I'm doing something wrong rather than this being a problem with Client.php

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Director needs to be in the same directory as your file.  If its not your going to have to edit all the `required_once`'s yourself.  Here is some working code for use with the Google Analytics API.

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

       foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

    }
 print "<br><br><br>";
 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

You can find a tutorial for this code at [Google Oauth2 PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/), there is a little test app at the bottom where you can see it working.